# Program for translating English to Morsecode JAVA

Tags: java

I am having trouble on a program that is supposed to translate English to morse code.

```
public class MorseCode
 {
  private static String [] english = { "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l", "m","n","o","p", "q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"};
  private static ArrayList<String> morse = new ArrayList<String> ();
  public MorseCode(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
     while(inFile.hasNext()){
         morse.add(inFile.next());
    }
        }

    public static void toMorse(String a)
    {
        String [] phrase = a.split("");  
        String translated = "";
        for (String b : phrase)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
            {
                if (b == english[i])
                {
                 translated += morse.get(i);
                 System.out.println(translated);
                }

            }


        }

        System.out.println(translated);
    }
```

}

Basically, I have an array of english letters/numbers in the String array [] English.
The Array List morse contains a list of morse characters that is read in from a file. The English Array and Morse Array List are the same length and correspond in terms of translation.

In the toMorse function, I have a String array phrase[] that has each individual letter of the user inputted message that is to be translated. 
For each letter in the message (each index in phrase[]), I go through each letter of the alphabet (english[]), and when I find a match, I take the same index of the match, and append the morse character of that index into a string.

I don't see any errors, but when I run the program there is just blank space after I type the message I want to be translated. I can't get the result to print out. I have made sure that most everything works, but I think there is something wrong in the for and if statements.

I have a separate class to run this:

```
public class MorseCodeTester
{
   public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
{
    MorseCode m = new MorseCode ("morsecode.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a message to translate to Morse Code: ");
    String message = in.next();
    message = message.toLowerCase();
    m.toMorse(message);
}
```

}

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I changed the "if (b == english[i])" to "if (b.equals(english[i]))" and now it prints out morsecode, but when I type more than one word, it just prints out the translation of the first word.

Comment: That's another problem. Btw you should learn to debug.

Comment: What's supposed to go in "morsecode.txt"? I'm trying to test your code but I don't know if I'm supposed to put morse code or english into it.